# Keyring stops working after first get_password() call when running Flask project with gunicorn in supervisor

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, python-keyring

I'm trying to run a instance of a flask project with gunicorn on supervisor and I'm facing a issue where I'm not able to retrieve passwords from keyring after the first `get_password()` is called. After that, everything returns `None`.

When running the Flask project alone or with gunicorn, it works, but when I apply it in the supervisor this happens.
What could I be missing?

This is the .conf file that I'm using to start the app:

```
[program:myflaskproject]
command=/my/project/path/venv/bin/gunicorn --preload wsgi:app --name my-app --workers 15 --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 --timeout 60 --log-level=debug --log-file=-
directory=/my/project/path
user=myuser
stdout_logfile=/my/project/path/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
```

There's simply no error. Keyring's `get_credentials()` and `get_password()` simply returns `None`

Edit:
Just noticed it works when I do not specify a user. What could I do to avoid an issue like that? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brief explanation of what I found out:

[Keyring uses Pathlib to find the current .local/share folder in home environment](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/ba4ce89049c400670a71d38f630cf56605398394/keyring/util/platform_.py#L25) and [Pathlib uses `~` to look for the home folder](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pathlib.py#L865) (where the password database is stored), which is resolved to your `$HOME` environment variable.

What is causing the issue is that when Supervisor starts a process, even with a specified user, it starts it with the `root` environment variables.

By looking at the [current Keyring code](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/ba4ce89049c400670a71d38f630cf56605398394/keyring/util/platform_.py#L26), the home folder provided by Pathlib is only used when the environment variable `XDG_DATA_HOME` is not set.

So to fix this, you can set the environment variable `XDG_DATA_HOME` at the Supervisor config pointing to the local share in the user home folder.

The final `.conf` will look like this:

```
[program:myflaskproject]
environment=XDG_DATA_HOME=/home/myuser/.local/share
command=/my/project/path/venv/bin/gunicorn --preload wsgi:app --name my-app --workers 15 --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 --timeout 60 --log-level=debug --log-file=-
directory=/my/project/path
user=myuser
stdout_logfile=/my/project/path/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
```